# multiple auto-resizable UILabels in table cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uilabel

I'm trying to put three `UILabel` in a cell of a table in iOS6. The first one is a number and is on the left, the second one is the title and is next to the first one, and the third one is a date placed on the right side of the cell. 
The date and the title resize themselves correctly according to the length of the text, but when the title is a long one it should be truncated before the date, instead it appears also over the date.

How do I get the title to truncate before the date? I have also tried to set its frame width and using `sizeToFit`, but with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this condition for the expansion of your TitleLabel:

```
    titleLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 20)];
    dateLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(160,0, 160, 20)];
    [self.view addSubview:titleLabel];
    [self.view addSubview:dateLabel];
    titleLabel.text=@"sjlkfdsfjdfkdlfjlkdsjflkdfjkldsfkdjfkljdslkjflkdslkf";
    dateLabel.text=@"fmldf";
    [titleLabel sizeToFit];
    if(titleLabel.frame.origin.x+titleLabel.frame.size.width>dateLabel.frame.origin.x)
    {
      titleLabel.frame=CGRectMake(titleLabel.frame.origin.x, titleLabel.frame.origin.y, 
          dateLabel.frame.origin.x-titleLabel.frame.origin.x-5, 20);
    }
    else
    {
        [titleLabel sizeToFit];
    }
```

Comment: frame.size.width is a read only property, moreover I have pointed out that setting the frame and using sizeToFit has no effect at all. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
myLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

**EDIT**:

```
cell.YOURLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

**OPTION 2**

```
[YOURLabel sizeToFit];
```

Comment: wouldn't this change only the font size? I need to adjust the width of the label to fit between the number and the date

Answer (score 0):

Just set the title label to the maximum allowable width in Interface Builder and set the Line Breaks option to the desired truncation mode. Or are you wanting the maximum allowable width to vary based on the width of the date label?

Comment: I have already tried that - it seemed the obvious way... but for some reason when I do so, the label of the number doesn't get resized anymore

Comment: Then it might be that you need to fix an issue with the number label. I don't think the title label shouldn't affect the number label unless possibly you're using Auto Layout, in which case you'd need to revisit your constraints.